# Removing language code from URL?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, iframe, http-status-code-404

I am working on a wordpress project and I need to insert an internal html file into an .

The problem I am running into is I am getting 404 not found errors and when I check the google console the source of the file is incorrect, because the website uses a multi-language plugin. Below is the iframe code.

```html
<iframe src="<?php echo bloginfo('template_url');?>/PapiModules/sharegraph.html" width="100%" height="1000px" frameBorder="0" scrolling='no' seamless></iframe>
```

As you can see below, the plugin is automatically adding "sv" into the url, thus breaking the source which throws a 404 error.

> http://noteeu.staging.wpengine.com/svwp-content/themes/note/PapiModules/sharegraph.html

I wonder if anyone knows how to remove that "sv" or add a "/" between "sv" and "wp-content" so that my source url is correct, without removing the language plugin?

Comment: echo bloginfo('template_url'); and see whats happened

Comment: The return is still "http://noteeu.staging.wpengine.com/svwp-content/themes/note/PapiModules/sharegraph.html "

Comment: I mean not in url. take it out

Comment: Not sure if I am doing what you asked, but this is the return in console when I only use what you write:

http://noteeu.staging.wpengine.com/svwp-content/themes/note

Comment: Hmm, Not sure but try remove echo

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42174136/can-you-change-the-value-of-the-bloginfo-in-the-general-template-of-wordpress

Answer (score 0):

I was able to add a "/" between the SV and the directories with:

```html
<?php echo get_home_url( '/' ); ?>
```

But it would still be optimal to be able to remove SV from the url.